# BiBTeX entries for RFCs?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

How does one get BibTeX entries for RFCs? do I need to manually add entries for each RFC I cite? What do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are [many](http://www.google.com/search?q=RFC+bibtex) automatically generated bib files you don't have to manually add them, and it shows how everyone else does it.

As a side note, its a simple matter to define a new driver with [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html).
Using `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{rfc}{...}`
and use `\DeclareFieldFormat[rfc]{...}{...}` if you want the field printed differently from the rest of the entry types. (I don't have any experience referencing RFCs, so @misc might fit well).